# Apache sites error after phpmyadmin installed

Tags: python, apache, phpmyadmin, mod-wsgi

I have had some sites on my Apache webserver. Sites configured like this:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/academmedia/academmedia/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess academmedia user=devlogin3 group=devlogin3 home=/var/www/acad$
WSGIProcessGroup academmedia
```

Everything worked well untill I installed phpmyadmin that reconfigured apache, now there are still files in `sites-available` but on `apache2 restart` I get warnings:

`module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping`

and when triyng to reach sites from browser - Internal server Error.

Comment: Check logs. Probably at `/var/log/Apache2/error.log`.

Comment: logs at `/var/log/htppd/`